# How catch click on button jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to catch the button click. This is the html code:

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-defaultid" id="button_id" value="Answer">
```

And in Jquery:

```
$('#button_id').on('click', function() {
            console.log("HI");

        });
```

But when I click the console.log doesn't print. Anyone can help me?

Comment: are u included jQuery library in ur page?

Comment: Make sure you are including jQuery. It does work: https://jsfiddle.net/7pu0jdu4/

Comment: yes!! the library is included!

Comment: Is your element dynamic? Perhaps you need to properly delegate this event if so

Comment: You need to bind event once element is available in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button_id').on('click',function() {
        console.log("HI");
    });
});
```